# Does it make sense to specify precision and scale for BigDecimal when it has already set in DB (Oracle)?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Does it make sense to specify precision and scale for BigDecimal when it has already set in DB (Oracle)?

```
@Column(name = "TEST_COLUMN", precision = 10, scale = 4)
```

vs

```
@Column(name = "TEST_COLUMN")
```

Considering that in DB the column has been specified as following:

```
NUMBER(10,4)
```

Does the precision remain once Hibernate reads it or there is the need of specifying it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like columnDefinition, it is only relevant for DDL generation.

From the Javadoc:

```
/**
 * (Optional) The precision for a decimal (exact numeric) 
 * column. (Applies only if a decimal column is used.)
 * Value must be set by developer if used when generating 
 * the DDL for the column.
 */
int precision() default 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify the precision/scale in hibernate. Once it's defined in the database, hibernate will ignore this property.

You only need to specify precision/scale if you want to have hibernate create the tables. Otherwise these properties are superfluous

Comment: could you link a source confirming of your statement?

Comment: personal experience having multiple applications querying `BigDecimals` from a database without having precision/scale provided in the mapping. Also that is easily test-able (what you should have done before even asking here)

Comment: it was just proof of concept, no means of testing it in this moment.